# How to set coordinates when cropping an image with PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-3.x, image-processing

I don't know how to set the coordinates to crop an image in `PIL`s `crop()`:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("Supernatural.xlsxscreenshot.png")
img2 = img.crop((0, 0, 201, 335))
img2.save("img2.jpg")
```

I tried with `gThumb` to get coordinates, but if I take an area which I would like to crop, I can only find position 194 336. Could someone help me please?

This is my picture:

[image]

I wish to crop to this:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### How to set the coordinates to crop

In the line:

```
img2 = img.crop((0, 0, 201, 335))
```

the first two numbers define the *top-left* coordinates of the outtake (x,y), while the last two define the *right-bottom* coordinates of the outtake.

#### Cropping your image

To crop your image like you show, I found the following coordinates: top-left: `(200, 330)`, and right-bottom: `(730, 606)`. Subsequently, I cropped your image with:

```
img2 = img.crop((200, 330, 730, 606))
```

[image]

with the result:

[image]

Comment: but I pressed the arrow. Is that not as "accepted"? I'm so stupid. Really dont know how to do :(

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I found it finally. I'm sorry that I din't know. Thnak you for your great help :)

Answer (score 3):

@Jacob Vlijm thankx for the great explanation.

But, those who are in hurry or are stupid like me -
here is an abstraction-:)

[image: python pillow coordinate system abstraction]